# Search in mutt by date and time

Tags: mutt

I've been using `mutt` for some days now, and I think I have the basics by now.

I'm able to search messages by date (`l`, `~d date ...`) but what I need is to also search by time.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible without patching `mutt`, however you could limit to:

```
~d <1d ~h '^Date:.*(1[3-9]|2.):..:'
```

To list the emails that have been sent today after 13:00 (in their own timezone).

To check the date in your timezone, you may be able to rely on the fact that there should be a `Received` header added by a MTA in your timezone (especially if it goes through a MTA on your machine). Then you could do:

```
~r <1d ~h '^Received:.*(1[3-9]|2.):..:.. \+0100'
```

(`+0100` is the time zone offset where I live (`+0000` in winter), it may be different for you).

You can also do the selection manually:

- sort by sent or received date
- note the first (`x`) and last (`y`) message you wish to see.
- limit using `~m x-y`

Comment: Thanks, this is good workaround which I use also in other scripts, I mean filtering dates in regex ...